# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content' in discord.py (pycord)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

I'm trying To make a function that waits for someone message in pycord. And when I'm trying to check it it tells me this error `discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content`
Here's my code

```
def check(ctx):
            c.execute("SELECT price FROM accounts WHERE type=?", (type,))
            price = c.fetchall()
            return ctx.message.content.startswith(f"**:moneybag: | {ctx.author.display_name}, has transferred ") and "<@969279390447984660>" in ctx.message and ctx.author.id == 282859044593598464 and price[0][0] in ctx.message
```

And here's Where I call the function:

```
        await bot.wait_for('message', check=check(message), timeout=60)
```

the full traceback is:

```
Ignoring exception in command buy:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 127, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(arg)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 911, in _invoke 
    await self.callback(ctx, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Sidtho\main.py", line 94, in buy
    await bot.wait_for('message', check=check(message), timeout=60)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Sidtho\main.py", line 80, in check
    return ctx.message.content.startswith(f"**:moneybag: | {ctx.author.display_name}, has transferred ") and "<@969279390447984660>" in ctx.message and ctx.author.id == 282859044593598464 and price[0][0] in ctx.message
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 1008, in invoke_application_command
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 359, in invoke  
    await injected(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 135, in wrapped 
    raise ApplicationCommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content'
```

note the command is a slash_command

edit:

I tried to change ctx.message to message:

here's what I tried:

```py
def check(message):
            c.execute("SELECT price FROM accounts WHERE type=?", (type,))
            price = c.fetchall()
            return message.content.startswith(f"**:moneybag: | {message.author.display_name}, has transferred ") and "<@969279390447984660>" in message.content and message.author.id == 282859044593598464 and price[0][0] in message.content
```

the traceback was: `discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'ApplicationContext' object has no attribute 'content'`

the full traceback is:

```
Ignoring exception in command buy:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 127, in wrapped 
    ret = await coro(arg)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 911, in _invoke 
    await self.callback(ctx, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Sidtho\main.py", line 94, in buy
    await bot.wait_for('message', check=check(message), timeout=60)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Sidtho\main.py", line 80, in check
    return message.content.startswith(f"**:moneybag: | {message.author.display_name}, has transferred ") and "<@969279390447984660>" in message.content and message.author.id == 282859044593598464 and price[0][0] in message.content
AttributeError: 'ApplicationContext' object has no attribute 'content'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 1008, in invoke_application_command
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 359, in invoke  
    await injected(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 135, in wrapped 
    raise ApplicationCommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'ApplicationContext' object has no attribute 'content'
```

Comment: In the current invocation of your function, `ctx.message` is `None`. You should test for that, and not attempt to access `ctx.message.content` when the message doesn't exist.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Looking at part of the line that failed, `ctx.message.content` - that is a lookup of "content" on the `ctx.message` object. _'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content"_ means that `ctx.message` must have been `None`. I'm not a discord user and I couldn't find a definite statement on its website, but it looks from their examples that `ctx.message` should not be None. But maybe that's not the case. You'll need a discord expert for that.

Comment: `ctx.message` generally shouldn't be none, but OP isn't even getting a `Context` instance at all here so `ctx.message` doesn't exist in this case. The `check` function gets a `Message` as its argument, not `Context`.

Answer (score 0):

Your check receives a `Message` as its input, not `Context`. `Message.message` doesn't exist, the argument passed into that check *is already the message*.

```py
def check(message):
    ...
    return message.content...
    #      ^ There is no ctx, "message" is the message
```

Your invocation is also incorrect:

```py
await bot.wait_for('message', check=check(message), timeout=60)
                                       # ^
```

You're supposed to *pass the function* into it, not *call it*.

```py
await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60)
#                                   ^ Don't call it, just pass it on
```

(the `message` doesn't exist yet at that point so you can't even call it)

The minimal `wait_for` example from the docs also shows both of these things... https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for